# How to safely send sensitive data from browser to server?

Tags: php, security, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a form for name, address, bank account, iban on my website.

When the user clicks the submit button, the data gets sent to my server via PHP and is stored in my MySQL database.

How can I prevent someone from grabbing the data while it is sent from the browser to my server?

Is an SSL certificate the right way? And if so, is an SSL certificate enough?

I found this website: [www.selfsignedcertificate.com](http://www.selfsignedcertificate.com). You can create a certificate for free. What's the difference between a paid and a free SSL certificate?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I prevent somebody grabs the data while they get send from the
>   browser to my server?

SSL prevents MITM (Man in the middle) attacks nicely.

> Is a SSL certificate the right way? And if, is an SSL certificate enough?

SSL certificate is the right way to provide *a layer of security.* BUT it is not enough. SQL Injection attacks are still possible. (Many other attacks also)

> I found this website: www.selfsignedcertificate.com. You can create a certificate for free. What's the difference between a paid and a free SSL certificate?

SSL certificates are generated by a **signing authority**. So these signing authorities charge you to verify that you really own the domain you're claiming. When you yourself become the signing authority, the certificate becomes free, (because you dont charge yourself to verify that you are you :P). And, the 'free' SSL cert will show a red bar on all browsers, because the browser does not trust the signing authority, that is you. More on this here : https://www.globalsign.com/en/ssl-information-center/what-is-an-ssl-certificate/

Answer (score 0):

I've just answered a very [similar question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(algorithm)) a few minutes ago.

> SSL is the standard. It provides:
>
> - **Confidentiality**: the data is encrypted between the client and the server and cannot be read by an attacker. Typically uses the [RSA
>     algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(algorithm)).
> - **Integrity**: an attacker cannot tamper with the messages sent between the client and the server. Typically implemented using
>     [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code?oldformat=true)
> - **Authentication**: the browser is able to check that the server it is talking to *is* actually yours, and not an attacker. Basically, the
>     server shows to the browser a certificate signed by the Certificate
>     Authority having issued the SSL certificate (e.g. VeriSign), that
>     proves its identity.
>
> All that is assuming SSL is configured properly on the server's side:
>   up-to-date ciphers, no support for outdated ones, proper key length
>   (2048 bits or higher), etc.
>
> You can use [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) to check if your SSL configuration looks
>   secure. Also, be sure to enforce your users to use SSL, for instance
>   by automatically redirecting *http://* URLs to *http**s**://* ones.

Answer (score 0):

SSL Certificate is the best option to prevent someone from grabbing data traveling between browser and server. But Self-signed certificate is not a solution as it won't be trusted by most of web browsers because it is not issued Trusted Certificate Authority. To overcome from this issue, I suggest you to get SSL issued by trusted CA. You will have to pay few dollars but it is worth investment. Big downside of self-signed certificate is, browsers will not consider it valid and will blow warning message to the users. It will not create great impression in users' mind.

As per the CAB Forum guidelines, certificate issued by CA should have minimum 256-bit encryption but you will not have such high encryption in the case of self-signed certificate. Paid SSL will be a good option instead of opting self-signed certificate. You can read this [SSL FAQs](https://www.cheapsslshop.com/faqs) to solve more doubts on SSL Certificates.

Answer (score -1):

```
<form name='form1' method="post" action="nextpage.php">
    <input type="text" name="t1" value="firstname">
    <input type="text" name="t2" value="secondname">
    <input type="submit" name="submit1">
</form>
 nextpage.php 
<?php
    echo $_POST['t1'];
    echo $_POST['t2'];
 ?>
```